# Is there any way to assure a ARRAY size match it's expected in compile?

Tags: arrays, macros

The mem_pool_tbl is an array table and the index is the TBL_ID_TYPE enum,

```
typedef enum
{
    TBL_ID_BEGIN = 0;
    TBL_ID_1,
    TBL_ID_2,
    TBL_ID_MAX,
}TBL_ID_TYPE;

int mem_pool_tbl[TBL_ID_TYPE]=
{1,2,3,4}
```

I wander if ther is a way looks like below to check if size/ID are macth while in compile like below :

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x)  (sizeof(x) /  sizeof(x[0]))

#define CHECK_TBL_MISMATCH  ((TBL_ID_MAX - TBL_ID_BEGIN ) != ARRAY_SIZE(mem_pool_tbl))

#if CHECK_NV_TBL_MISMATCH
# Hi there, if you see compiler err here , check the tbl if the ID is match 
#endif
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `int mem_pool_tbl[TBL_ID_MAX]` there?

Comment: The int mem_pool_tbl[TBL_ID_MAX] is used for store some device config info for driver look up from it, it's stored as a global var.   Since the info table is more than 1000  ,I just want to make sure that others will adding info to the table and the INDEX enum is just match the array

Comment: You wrote TBL_ID_TYPE.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support range-checking arrays (though some compilers have a static analyzer that will try to detect such bugs using a heuristic). It also does not really have a way to determine the size of an array in general, as arrays are just a range of bytes, and can be in the middle of a stack variable or heap block.

There are, however, two approaches you can use:

1) Wrap up creation of arrays, thus preventing clients from using them wrongly. E.g.

Header:

```
struct OpaqueTBLArray;

struct OpaqueTBLArray*  MallocTblArray();
void                    FreeTblArray();
int                     GetTblArray( struct OpaqueTBLArray* self, size_t idx );
void                    SetTblArray( struct OpaqueTBLArray* self, size_t idx, int value );
```

Implementation source file:

```
struct OpaqueTBLArray
{
    int     mem_pool_tbl[TBL_ID_MAX];
}

struct OpaqueTBLArray*  MallocTblArray()
{
    return (OpaqueTBLArray*) malloc( sizeof(OpaqueTBLArray) );
}

void                    FreeTblArray( OpaqueTBLArray* self )
{
    free( self );
}

int                     GetTblArray( struct OpaqueTBLArray* self, size_t idx )
{
    return self->mem_pool_tbl[idx];
}


void                    SetTblArray( struct OpaqueTBLArray* self, size_t idx, int value )
{
    self->mem_pool_tbl[idx] = value;
}
```

This way, nobody using your struct will know what size it is or be able to give something else without a lot more effort. This approach can also be used for a generic array class if you just add a size field to the struct, for instance.

2) If your array is always a stack variable in local scope, you can use the sizeof() operator on it and divide by sizeof(int). However, this only works with a directly, locally declared fixed-size array, and not in the preprocessor.